# Connecting to Twilio Video API

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

I am trying to test the twilio-php video sdk in chrome from the guide  [QuickStart guide](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/guide/quickstart-android). Got the the required credentials from the twilio api console (api key and configuration profile sid), and pasted it in the given code to generate access token:

```
require_once('./twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php');
require_once('./randos.php');

$TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$TWILIO_CONFIGURATION_SID = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy';
$TWILIO_API_KEY = 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz';
$TWILIO_API_SECRET = 'kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk';

// An identifier for your app - can be anything you'd like
$appName = 'TwilioVideoDemo';

// choose a random username for the connecting user
$identity = randomUsername();

// Create access token, which we will serialize and send to the client
$token = new Services_Twilio_AccessToken(
    $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, 
    $TWILIO_API_KEY, 
    $TWILIO_API_SECRET, 
    3600, 
    $identity
);

// Grant access to Conversations
$grant = new Services_Twilio_Auth_ConversationsGrant();
$grant->setConfigurationProfileSid($TWILIO_CONFIGURATION_SID);
$token->addGrant($grant);

// return serialized token and the user's randomly generated ID
echo json_encode(array(
    'identity' => $identity,
    'token' => $token->toJWT(),
));
```

The token is generated properly and is passed properly to the localhost but the log says **Could not connect to Twilio: undefined...** all the time.

[image: Screenshot of log]

Hoping to get a solution for this.

Comment: Twilio evangelist here. I'd suggest popping open the Javascript console in your browser and making sure that the token is being returned from your web page correctly and there are no other client-side errors happening.  If there are, feel free to drop those errors into your question and we can help you with those.

Comment: @DevinRader : There are no errors, the token and identity are returned from the server successfully.

Comment: @qwery_coder: can you take the token and drop it into the tester on http://jwt.io.  In the payload section you should see your Account SID, API Key SID and Configuration profile SID.

Comment: @DevinRader : I tried that, returns all valid values.

Comment: @qwery_coder: can you put a breakpoint on line 22 of index.js (the console.log line) and see if the `error` object is null

Comment: @DevinRader : Ok, i got the data.identity, data.token values and after that i get this: "accessManager = i {_events: Object, _maxListeners: undefined}" .